# Plotting a parabola based on data points

Tags: curves, least-squares, bezier-curve

I am trying to draw a parabola inside a chart which I am developing using D3.Js library and using SVG paths to draw the curve.

I have a set of 5 points for drawing the parabola: `(0, 500) (100, 400) (200, 280) (300, 220) (400, 200)`.

[Points plot image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ya5ZT.png)

But to plot these points I need to know the control points so a perfect and smooth curve is obtained like below.

[Example chart based on data points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hi3KL.png)

Is there any equation or way to identify the control points for two point, so that its possible to draw a parabola touching the points specified above?

**Edit**

Is it possible with a Bezier cure?

Comment: Does the parabola need to go **exactly** through the mentioned points?

Comment: @MattiP. yes, it needs to go

Comment: @ Hari Krishna: Curve fitting is allowed? Given curve has an inflection point, so a parabola passing through them all is impossible.Also only four points define a parabola. Also should its axis be parallel to one of the coordinate axes?

Comment: @Narasimham I understand, Instead of a parabola, Is it possible with a quadratic bezier curve?

Comment: Yes, cubic and quintic splines are possible.

Comment: @Narasimham Thats great, Is there any equation to find the control points?

Comment: Just a comment, if we take just the first three points, there is a unique parabola that passes through them, and that is
$$
f(x) = \frac{-1}{1000}x^2 - \frac{9}{10}x + 500
$$
It passes through the first three points but not the others. Therefore, there is no parabola that passes through all the points.

Comment: @MattiP. I understand, Is it possible with a quadratic bezier curve, so that it touches all points? Any equation to identify control points?

Comment: In the question it is not specified that the axis of the parabola must be parallel to the y-axis. The parabola can be defined exactly with four points. But even taking account of this remarque, it is easy to check that no parabola fits exactly to the given data of five points. A mean least square regression can provide an approximate fitting of a parabola with inclined axis. I will not give the result of this calculus because I think that the question has been put in the wrong way. I vote to close the question until the OP edit again the question in order to express definitively what he want.

Answer (score 0):

If the points don't fall precisely on a parabola there is nothing whatsoever you can do about that:

[image]

Comment: Is this possible with a Bezier curve?

Comment: That would not be a quadratic, and hence not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

By least squares method we can find four constants $(a,b,c,d)$ from given data using base relation of a tilted parabola whose symmetry axis is inclined to the coordinate axes:

$$ (y+ax+b)^2 = cx+d$$

Answer (score 0):

A parabola whose axis of symmetry is vertical can pass through three given points.

A (rotated) parabola can pass through four given points. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/393664/curve-through-four-points-simple-algebra) for details.

A quadratic Bezier curve is the same thing as a rotated parabola, so, again, it can interpolate four points.

A cubic Bezier curve can interpolate 6 points. See [my answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/393302/forcing-bezier-interpolation/393618#393618) for details.